# Convert html Inside tag (span class=) to XML tag

Tags: xslt

I always find how to convert Tag to inside tag but I fail to do the opposite.

I have that:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title>Entry1</title>
<link rel="self" href="https://google.com"/>
<content type="xhtml">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <span class="firstname">John</span>
        <span class="lastname">Doe</span>
        <div class="update_information">
            <span class="update_date">2018-05-05T04:05:03Z</span>
            <span class="update_author">xxx@google.com</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</content>
```

With this XLST:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:for-each select="@*[local-name()!='span']">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I retrieve the data

```
<entry>
  <title>Entry1</title>
  <link>
  <rel>self</rel>
  <href>https://google.com</href>   </link>
  <content>
  <type>xhtml</type>
        <div>
              <span><class>firstname</class>John</span>
              <span><class>lastname</class>Doe</span>
        <div>
        <class>update_information</class>
                    <span><class>update_date</class>2018-05-05T04:05:03Z</span>
                    <span><class>update_author</class>xxx@google.com</span>
         </div>
        </div>
  </content>
```

But I am expecting to have:

```
<entry>
  <title>Entry1</title>
  <link> <href>https://google.com</href>  </link>
  <content>
  <type>xhtml</type>
        <div>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <lastname>Doe</lastname>
        <language>en</language>
        <div>
        <class>update_information</class>
            <update_date>2018-05-05T04:05:03Z</update_date>
            <update_author>xxx@google.com</update_author>
        </div>
        </div>
  </content>
```

As we can see I extracted the value in span but need now to create a tag with it.

in fact I need to convert `<span class="firstname">John</span>` to `<firstname>John</firstname>`.

Thank you to help me.

regards,

Comment: edited with my trial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title>Entry1</title>
<updated>2018-05-05T04:05:03Z</updated>
<content type="xhtml">
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<span class="firstname">John</span>
<span class="lastname">Doe</span>
<div class="orgaloc">
<span class="orgaloc_name">Google</span>
</div>
<div class="update_information">
<span class="update_date">2018-05-05T04:05:03Z</span>
<span class="update_author">xxx@google.com</span>
</div>
</div>
</content>
</entry>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<xsl:output method = "xml" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()][parent::*]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="parent::*/@class">
            <xsl:element name="{parent::*/@class}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:element name="{parent::*/name()}"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:element></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[child::node()]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name()='entry'">
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot both solutions are working and fitting the need.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
exclude-result-prefixes="x">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:span">
    <xsl:element name="{@class}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```